# com.googlecode.objectify.LoadException: timestamp out of range error

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, timestamp, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

In my datastore somehow the timestamp was saved as an Integer, something like this `-8499613106649`. 
While reading that entity, Objectify is throwing the below exception:

```
com.googlecode.objectify.LoadException: Error loading Key{projectId=**********}]}: timestamp out of range: 8499613106648, 250560000
```

I tried to modify the timestamp in the `@onLoad` method and append an `l` at the end of the Integer so that it won't throw an exception. But it's not working, as the Entity was not able to Load.

Is there a way I could modify the timestamp before loading or catch the Exception and modify the timestamp and save to datastore?

Comment: To give more info about the error, I would add the full stacktrace and the the code that caused the Error. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty strange - it might help if you posted the full stacktrace. I'm curious what originates that message.

There are a few ways of dealing with "there's something icky in my datastore".

- Change the type of your field to Long (or String or whatever) and convert to a Date/Instant/whatever in your getter method. You can revert the change after you've re-saved your data in the correct format.
- Write your own `Translator` for this type that accepts more generous input. Look at the existing translators in the Objectify source.
- Use the low-level API to rewrite the "corrupt" data.

Which I'd pick depends on the codebase and how hard it is to de-funk the data.